# How to transfer design from Adobe XD to Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, adobe

I created webapp design in Adobe XD.

Now I want to create that design in Webstorm using Bootstrap framework and HTML.

Is there tool, which can recognize items from .xd files?

Or at least where I can create items in GUI, which translates my item into HTML (for example blue square button with text inside which changes opacity when having mouse arrow on it)?

Answer (score 3):

Some tools make it easier to convert the design to code, but you'll (probably) won't get around writing code to get a good website.

First of all, there is no real way to directly "convert" prototypes to websites. There are now some plugins to make things like this easier (e.g. "Lightning Storm CC"), but in all honesty, that doesn't get you around writing code yourself.

Also, it could be challenging to implement a custom design with Bootstrap (or did you use a Bootstrap UI Kit for Adobe XD?), since Bootstrap itself makes it quite tricky to achieve custom designs.

All in all, I think the solution you're looking for doesn't exist. Some tools are making it more comfortable, but you won't get around writing code when implementing a custom design. I think the truth is that there are two options: Implement a custom design (with code!) or don't care about the design aspects and use framework X (here Bootstrap).

Answer (score 1):

I think easiest way is to export the design from xd using any tools to html, here is another tool might be useful "web export"
after that you just have to implement bootstrap and start adding classes to your components button,input...etc
but as mr pklaschka said it's hard to do custom without getting your hand dirty with some codes 
good luck

Answer (score 0):

> Is there tool, which can recognize items from .xd files?
> Or at least where I can create items in GUI, which translates my item into HTML (for example blue square button with text inside which changes opacity when having mouse arrow on it)?

You can use Desech Studio to import your xd file and then you need to adjust some margins and sizes. This will convert it to vanilla html/css, not bootstrap.

After that you can switch to Webstorm and code your website there, or you can stay synced with Desech Studio and integrate with react, angular, vue etc.